# jquery validation fullname field regex prob

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

**In below code, iam using jquery validation..**

The prob is only for the FullName field.. when I just entered a FullName as "tom", it should show me some error, but its not showing currently... BUt when i enter as some 'harry potter'  (or) 'harry-potter' , it should not show any error....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>


     <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#fullname').focus();

                var validCharactersRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-z -]+$/);
                var doesNotStartWithDashOrSpace = new RegExp(/^[^ -]/);
                var fullname_invalid = function(value) {
                    return validCharactersRegex.test(value) && doesNotStartWithDashOrSpace.test(value) && value.indexOf('  ') == -1 && value.indexOf('--') == -1 && value.indexOf(' -') == -1 && value.indexOf('- ') == -1;
                }


                $.validator.addMethod("custom_fullname", function(value, element) {
                    return fullname_invalid(value);
                }, 'Your Name should be entered like: "blahblah"');

                $('#signup').validate({
                    rules: {
                        fullname: {
                            required: true,
                            custom_fullname: true
                        },                  
                        email: {
                          required: true,
                          email: true
                        }
                    },


                    messages: {
                        fullname : {
                          required: "Please specify your Full Name",             
                          custom_fullname : "Your Name should be entered like: fullname lastname  (or) fullname-lastname"
                        },
                        email: {
                          required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                          email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
                        }
                    }


                });

                $('#signup').on('submit', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });


             $("#phone").mask("(9999) 9999999");

            });

              </script> 


        <style>
                .error {color: red;}
        </style>


 </head>




 <body>

    <form id="signup" action="/action">

        Full Name: <input name="fullname" type="text"  maxlength="14" /><br/>
        Email <input id="email" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" /><br/>
        Telephone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br/>


    Select Country: <select>
          <option value="South Yorkshire" selected>South Yorkshire</option>
          <option value="Rest of England">Rest of England</option>
          <option value="Wales, Scotland">Wales, Scotland</option>
          <option value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland</option>
          <option value="European Union">European Union</option>
          <option value="Rest of World">Rest of World</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select><br/>


        <input type="submit">

    </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

**please kindly check someone..**

Comment: Your regular expression only allows lowercase letters.

Comment: You can combine your two regular expressions: /^[a-z][- a-z]+$/

Comment: Your code is confusing. The name of the function is fullname_ **invalid**. But the regex checks for **valid** names, while the `indexOf()` checks are for **invalid** names.

Comment: I just edited above Tom as tom and 'Harry Potter' as 'harry potter' (actually I do not need any uppercase letter..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do everything in a single regex:

```
var validCharactersRegex = /^[a-z][- a-z]*[- ]{2}[- a-z]*[a-z]$/i;
function fullname_valid(value) {
    return validCharactersRegex.test(value);
}

$.validator.addMethod("custom_fullname", function(value, element) {
    return fullname_valid(value);
}, 'Your Name should be entered like: "blahblah"');
```

This requires that it begin with a letter, end with a letter, contain only letters, spaces, and dashes, and have a separator of either space-space, dash-dash, space-dash, or dash-space somewhere in it.

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kE8XX/1/)

Comment: HI Barmer, iam sorry that previously i given wrong info... Actually what I need is:   when I just entered a FullName as "tom", it should show me some error, but its not showing currently... BUt when i enter as some 'harry potter' (or) 'harry-potter' , it should not show any error....

Comment: So, could you please change again the value for : validCharactersRegex  ??

Comment: My version gives an error for tom, and no error for harry--potter. If you only need one space or hyphen between names, change `[- ]{2}` to just `[- ]`. If you don't allow uppercase, remove the `i` modifier.